# How to remove the prompt when execute shell command in Vim

Tags: vim

When I use :! to execute a shell command, I always get the following prompt text from Vim.
"Press ENTER or type command to continue"

[image]

I just want to remove the prompt, since I use this command frequently, I don't want to press the enter key every time. Is this possible?

Comment: In this example, you will not see any `ls` output.

Comment: So how did you get this to work? The currently accepted answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
:silent !ls
```

But, if the command produces any output it will leave the screen in an inconsistent state.  In that case you'd need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or `:redraw` to fix that.

Run `:help :!` from within vim for more information.

Comment: Would be great if you showed the final result.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work but it's not happening. Keep on seeing that prompt.